# Google Sheets, cell counter that counts every time a cells values change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a counter going in google sheets that will count how many times a cell has changed or updated.

I want cell "K1" to count how many times cell "Client!A2" values have changed.

This is my first time using Apps-Script so I feel like I must be missing something here.  This is what has been input into the code.gs section.

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if(e.range.getA2Notation() == "Client!A2") {
    var sCounter = e.source.getRange("K1");
    var counter = sCounter.getValue();

    if(counter === 0) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter ++;
    }
    sCounter.setValue(counter);  
  }  
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working,
Am I supposed to be putting anything else in the brackets? Or am I just doing it wrong altogether?

Comment: you don't click "run" on an onEdit() function.  It just runs every time any cell on the spreadsheet is edited.  Try just saving it, then edting Client!A1 and watching to see if it works?

Comment: The function `onEdit()` is a special function (tirgger) that fires automatically whenever you edit something on your sheet. You can't run it from Script Editor. It's likely the function wont work. If you want to see the log messages have to open `Executions` (the side panel of Script Editor)

Comment: `e.range.getA1Notation()` will return you `A1`, not `Client!A1`. If you want to get a sheet name you have to use `var sheet_name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()` and then you can compare it this way: `if (sheet_name == 'Client`) { // etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];//included sheets
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx && e.value != e.oldValue) {
    let n = Number( PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('editcounter'));//counter
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('editcounter',++n);
    sh.getRange('K1').setValue(n);
    e.source.toast(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added the sheet names to where you put 'Sheet1','Sheet2' but where do i put the cell number  that I want the counter to be in?

Comment: I stored the number in PropertiesService

Comment: sorry I don't understand, I'm still very new at this, I'm not sure how to specify for the counter to go into cell "K1"